Privacy Recommendations
I recently moved into a home with great landscaping except for the side walkway. That side butts into the back patio of the neighbor's house since they're the corner lot. Therefore, there's a lot of exposure between us that I'm hoping to remedy with foliage of some kind.
Some notes:

I'm in zone 10b (San Diego)
The strip of land for planting is 4'6" x ~50' running north/south. See diagram below.
There is about 6 feet of clearance from our house to the planting
location and about 10 feet from the other house. Both houses are two
stories tall, so there is decent sunlight but more shade in the
winter.
The planting location currently has 3' shrubs and 16' skinny, sparse
trees (see pictures). I plan to have these all removed since they
aren't helping.
On the neighbor's side, which runs parallel next to the planting
location, they have 14-16' skinny trees (Lonicera Ciliosa) with light
to moderate foliage coverage but only between the 8-12' feet range.
Below that is minimal. These trees will remain so they'll have an
impact on the sunlight for the new plants.
There's a 4' shared fence between the properties.
I'm willing to pay for something nice. Pros would be reasonably
native to SoCal, easy to maintain, provide good privacy, drought
resistant, aesthetics, etc.
I'm OK waiting a year or two before the new plants grow and help out.
I don't necessarily want something fast growing if it's going to be a
beast to maintain.
I got a quote of $2-$3k for removal of existing trees/shrubs, plus
additional for planting the replacements. Seems reasonable given
size.
I was told the planting location could support 15 gallon plants.
I love the idea of having Italian cypress, but the lack of sunlight
and our neighbors’ trees seem like they would cause growth issues.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

From the front looking back

From the front looking back 2

From the middle looking front

From the back looking front

Backside (planning to remove the Ficus in the middle left and the tree left to it but keep everything to the right)

